# Reference for spectra theory (in topology)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

Is there any good reference for the theory of spectra (in topology)? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine who works in this field for his master thesis would recommend the freely avaiable *Introduction to Stable Homotopy Theory* by *Urs Schreiber* on nLab (see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+Stable+Homotopy+Theory)). As he says, it is the most modern approach to this topic.